# Send Android Parse Push Notification to segment

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, segment

I am trying to send push notifications to segment users in Android. Below is the code, it worked for few trials but now the same code send the push to everyone instead of the intended receiver (at the least that is what is shown on the dashboard). Anything I am doing wrong here?

```
ParseQuery pushQuery = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
pushQuery.whereEqualTo("user", ParseObject.createWithoutData("_User", mObject.get(position)));//receiver
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setQuery(pushQuery);
push.setMessage(alias +" followed you");
push.sendInBackground();
```

mObject.get(position) is where I get the objectId of the receiver in the installation class from and 'user' is a pointer to the _User class. Thanks

Comment: Have you verified with logging or debugging that `mObject.get(position)` is returning something that matches a user?

Comment: Yes @Nasch, I have verified that and even hard-coded an objectId but to no avail.

Comment: If the exact same code used to work correctly I don't know what the issue is.  I would see if you can figure out whether the messages are actually going to everyone - I would not be 100% confident that the parse dashboard is giving you accurate information.

Comment: Its true but I am just testing the app so I may have to install it on some devices before I can verify that

Comment: Yeah if you have at least a couple of devices, set up a test and see if they all get the push.